# string in index out of range grok learning

Tags: python

I am trying to make s programme that takes text and gives back to the user every 3rd letter including the first letter.This is what i wrote.

```
msg = input('Message? ')
for i in range(len(msg)):
   (i) = (i*3)
   print(msg[i], end=' ')
```

This gives back every thurd letter including the 1st letter but then also gives the error:

File "program.py", line 4, in 
    print(msg[i], end=' ')
IndexError: string index out of range

Also the software I am using says: Testing the first example but ignoring whitespace. Your submission raised an exception of type IndexError. This occurred on line 4 of your submission.

Whats the simplest way to fix this?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: your index will go out of range the moment you crosses 1/3 of the string

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the string "Here we are". It has length 11. You are letting `i` go all the way to the end of the string, but once `i` reaches `4`, that string at index `i * 3` (12) is not defined.  Instead, you shouldn't go farther than `i` divided by 3 (rounding down).  This is how you would do that:

```
msg = input('Message? ')
for i in range((len(msg) // 3) + 1):
   (i) = (i*3)
   print(msg[i], end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

what you want to do can easily be achieved by slicing the string

```
msg = input('Message? ')
print(msg[::3])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
msg = input("Message?: ")
count = 1
for i in msg:
    if count % 3 == 0:
        print("First char in string is " + msg[0] + ", the third is " + i)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the range in steps of 3:

```
msg = input('Message? ')
for i in range(0, len(msg), 3):
   print(msg[i], end=' ')
```